# Is it possible to control docker image tags using using pom.xml

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml, docker-swarm, docker-machine

- I have a Jenkins job which is used to build the docker image using the docker file from GitHub. The below Jenkins file is used to trigger Jenkins job.

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env groovy
  node('master')
  {
  checkout scm
  def customImage = docker.build("sample/mvn:latest")
  print(customImage)
  }
  ```

  **- Now I am trying to automate the docker tags in incremental (ex: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3) by using pom.xml. Any suggestions or could anyone suggest me another way to tag docker images.**

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](https://medium.com/travis-on-docker/how-to-version-your-docker-images-1d5c577ebf54) a nice solution to get inspired